# Example of 2 variables real function where you MUST use Fubini to integrate?

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where it's impossible to integrate respect to $x$ (as in "you don't get an elementary function") but if you integrate respect to $y$ first and then to $x$ you win.

I'm using [this](https://owlcation.com/stem/List-of-Functions-You-Cannot-Integrate-No-Antiderivatives) list to see if maybe I can build one from that but I'm not sure of what to do.

Comment: you can google: "change the order of integration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x,y) := e^{-x^2}$.
Integrate on the region $\{(x,y): 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1\}$.

Comment: That's a nice answer, but I'd need to see the region as a Type II region instead of a Type I region (I can't change the order of integration that easily). Do you happen to know of an example in a rectangular region? I'll accept your answer anyway, as it is correct (I had forgotten to do it).

Comment: Oh, I could think of one: $y e^{-x^2}$ in $[0,1] \times [-1,1]$

Answer (score 0):

Take some function $g(x)$ so that $g(x)e^{2\pi ikx}$ can't be integrated for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and then do something like $\int_1^2\int_1^2 g(x)e^{2\pi ixy}dxdy$. When you use Fubini, you get $0$.

Comment: I need a function defined in the real numbers...